# shortcut creation

Tags: shortcuts

is their any simple way to create desktop shortcut or menu shortcuts for any folder and executive files in Ubuntu 18.04.1 budgie .

or can you guys show me how to do it in step by step process through command line via any app/program.

Comment: thanks for the answer but its too many command line for 1 simple shortcut . and in new nautilus 3.26 i see no bookmark option.

Comment: I agree it is, but that is the situation atm. It is possible to drag a folder to the left pane (nautilus window) though. Time for a quicklist editor probably. You could request one for budgie here: https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/c/Suggestions-for-future-releases. I'd actually like the suggestion, and it can be discussed internally. You could also use Kangaroo on Budgie though to quickly access folder (Budgie Welcome -> Applets)

Comment: Removed the dupe link btw, since that is specific to nautilus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a menu editor (Menu Libre or Mozo) to create .desktop files with a graphical interface. Move the .desktop files under ./local/share/applications for them to show up in your menu, or place them in your ~/Desktop folder and set them executable to have them act as a launcher on the desktop.

This is not limited to Budgie, but to all desktop environments. Shortcuts on the desktop obviously only works provided your desktop environment provides an active desktop, and provided that is enabled.

Comment: thanks but i also want to create a shortcut for specific folder.

Comment: You can do that. The command will be `xdg-open /path/to/directory`.

Comment: thanks for showing me this but it like going back to old command line interference in the world of GUI base systems.

Comment: That is actually because having icon and launchers on the desktop tends to be phased out in modern desktops, like it or not. Gnome Shell by default does not support desktop icons: you can enable, though, in versions prior to the current 3.30. Obviously, they do not provide the graphical tools anymore. Yet, you still can drag from nautilus and firefox to create shortcuts to URL's or folders.